Should I add " does" in the following question?
Should I add " does" in the following question?

The meaning of "have" in here is to eat something or to ask somebody to give you something?


When you ask a question, you normally do something called subject-auxiliary inversion, where the subject and the auxiliary verb are swapped. In the following example, the auxiliary verb is have:

Statement: You have seen the film "Titanic".
Question: Have you seen the film "Titanic"?

If there is no auxiliary verb, you add Do/Does as a dummy auxiliary, in front of the subject:

Statement: You like noodles
Question: Do you like noodles?

The be-verb is an exception: in a sentence with a be-verb as a main verb, you swap it with the subject:

Statement: You are cold.
Question: Are you cold?

In your sentence, the main verb is is, so you don't need to add do/does: you simply swap it with the subject of the sentence:

Question: Is the meaning of "have" in here to eat something or to ask somebody to give you something?


This is not a standard way to phrase a question.  We don't normally simply add a question mark at the end of a statement to try and make it a question.
We can consider
Does "have" here mean 'to eat something' or 'to ask somebody to give you something'?
Is the meaning of "have" here 'to eat something' or 'to ask somebody to give you something'?

Your suggested sentences are correct, but you don't explain why they are correct.

Thanks, @JavaLatte.  You're right.  I should've gone a step further.  Now that that is already in your answer,  the boat has gone :)
